A complex identity
Let $z = e^{ i\theta }$, $c_k = \cos ( 2 \pi k /n)$ and $\zeta_k = e^{2 \pi i k /n }$
I am trying to prove or disprove:
$$ \dfrac{z^2-1}{z^2-2c_k z + 1 } =   1 + \dfrac{ \zeta_k}{z-\zeta_k} + \dfrac{ \bar{\zeta_k} }{z - \bar{\zeta_k}}$$
My thoughts:
$$ \dfrac{z^2-1}{z^2-2c_k z + 1 } = 1 + 2 \left( \dfrac{ c_k z - 1 }{z^2 - 2 c_k z + 1 } \right) $$
Now, evidently, we may decompose in partial fractions. However, I would like to see if anyone has a better, less algebraic solution to see this identity.

Try working in the opposite direction?  Or alternatively, just simplify $$\left(1 + \frac{ \zeta_k}{z-\zeta_k} + \frac{ \overline{\zeta_k} }{z - \overline{\zeta_k}}\right)(z^2-2c_kz + 1)$$
